# Remove empty lines from selected cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to remove only empty lines from cells in excel. Here is what I'm trying to accoplish:

```
+-----------------+    +---------------------+    +---------------------+
|  EXAMPLE DATA   |    |    EXPLANATION      |    |   EXPECTED RESULT   |
+-----------------+    +---------------------+    +---------------------+
| cell1_text1     |    | cell1_text1         |    | cell1_text1         |
| cell1_text2     |    | cell1_text2         |    | cell1_text2         |
+-----------------+    +---------------------+    +---------------------+
|                 |    | cell2_empty_line    |    | cell2_text1         | 
| cell2_text1     |    | cell2_text1         |    +---------------------+ 
+-----------------+    +---------------------+    | cell3_text1         | 
| cell3_text1     |    | cell3_text1         |    | cell3_text2         | 
|                 |    | cell3_emptyline     |    +---------------------+ 
| cell3_text2     |    | cell3_text2         |    | cell4_text1         | 
+-----------------+    +---------------------+    +---------------------+ 
|                 |    | cell4_emptyline     |    | cell5_text1         | 
|                 |    | cell4_emptyline     |    +---------------------+ 
| cell4_text1     |    | cell4_text1         |    | cell6_text1         | 
+-----------------+    +---------------------+    | cell6_text2         | 
| cell5_text1     |    | cell5_text1         |    | cell6_text3         | 
+-----------------+    +---------------------+    | cell6_text4         | 
| cell6_text1     |    | cell6_text1         |    +---------------------+ 
| cell6_text2     |    | cell6_text2         |
| cell6_text3     |    | cell6_text3         |
|                 |    | cell6_emptyline     |
| cell6_text4     |    | cell6_text4         |
+-----------------+    +---------------------+
```

I have [found this script](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/03/remove-carriage-returns-excel/):

```
Sub RemoveCarriageReturns()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    For Each MyRange In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If 0 < InStr(MyRange, Chr(10)) Then
            MyRange = Replace(MyRange, Chr(10), "")
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

but it doesn't give me desired result, it removes all breaklines in all cells.

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|          CURRENT SCRIPT RESULT              |
+---------------------------------------------+
| cell1_text1cell1_text2                      |
+---------------------------------------------+
| cell2_text1                                 |
+---------------------------------------------+
| cell3_text1cell3_text2                      |
+---------------------------------------------+
| cell4_text1                                 |
+---------------------------------------------+
| cell5_text1                                 |
+---------------------------------------------+
| cell6_text1cell6_text2cell6_text3cell6_text4|
+---------------------------------------------+
```

How can I test if row doesn't contain any other letter and delete only that row within cell?
How can I apply that macro only to currenty selected cells?

Comment: you only one to move values within between ----------------- lines right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to locate and remove errant line feed characters (e.g. vbLF, `Chr(10)` or ASCII 010 dec). If the data was copied from an external source, it is possible that rogue carriage return characters (e.g. vbCR or `Chr(13)`) may have piggy-backed along and these should be scrubbed as well.

```
Sub clean_blank_lines()
    Dim rw As Long
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet3")   '<~~SET THIS WORKSHEET REFERENCE PROPERLY!
        For rw = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            With .Cells(rw, 1)
                .Value = Replace(.Value2, Chr(13), Chr(10))
                Do While Left(.Value2, 1) = Chr(10): .Value = Mid(.Value2, 2): Loop
                Do While CBool(InStr(1, .Value, Chr(10) & Chr(10)))
                    .Value = Replace(.Value2, Chr(10) & Chr(10), Chr(10))
                Loop
                Do While Right(.Value2, 1) = Chr(10): .Value = Left(.Value2, Len(.Value2) - 1): Loop
            End With
            .Rows(rw).EntireRow.AutoFit
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

A [Range.AutoFit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820840.aspx) is performed on the finished cell to remove dead 'white space'.

[image: Trim Line Feeds]        [image: Trim line feed results]

                 <sub>Before</sub>                                <sub>After</sub>

To convert this to a macro that processes one or more selected cells, see [Examples of Selection-based sub framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/28700020#28700020) in [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/28700020).

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

Instead of replacing the carriage returns, split on it then loop through and replace the value with only those items that have a value.

```
Sub RemoveCarriageReturns()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    For Each MyRange In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        Dim textArr() As String
        textArr = Split(MyRange.Value, Chr(10))
        MyRange.Value = ""
        For i = LBound(textArr) To UBound(textArr)
            If textArr(i) <> "" Then
                If MyRange.Value = "" Then
                    MyRange.Value = textArr(i)
                Else
                    MyRange.Value = MyRange.Value & Chr(10) & textArr(i)
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```